# python High Pass Filter for image processing

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, scipy, highpass-filter

I want to use a High-pass Filter on my Image(see appendix). The High-pass Filter should remove the Gradient of the Line in the Image. My Goal is to get a line nearly without the Gradient.

i tried different Methods:
1. I use a Gaussian Filter on the Image and subtract the result from the Original Image like:

```
lowpass = ndimage.gaussian_filter(Image, 3)
gauss_highpass = Image - lowpass
```

2. I saved the Value of the Y-Coordinate of the Image in a Array and used the High-pass filter. 
   Unfortunately i dont get the result i want....

Image:

[image]

Comment: You can upload your image to a generic image hosting site (postimg, imgur) and [edit] the link into your question. Someone else will edit it further and include the actual picture.

Comment: `Unfortunately i dont get the result i want....` - you may want to be more specific here. What do you expect?

Comment: the right Line has a big Gradient. I want to have a nearly smooth line, because i want to match several Images.

Comment: What you are looking for is some kind of line interpolation (bivariate spline or something like that) that will give you a smooth approximation of the curve. Applying a denoising filter to the image won't make the curve smoother, it will just make the gradient smaller in the vecinity of the pixels (the gradient as the difference of the pixels within its neighbours, not the gradient of the line).